# VS code ssh connection issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

im trying to connect ssh on vs code.
I'm using Windows and I can make ssh connection on CLI (bash).
But everytime i tried on VS code, it gave me a following log.

```
[15:03:52.632] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 2343 cluster bash
[15:03:52.641] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:03:52.956] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[15:03:54.260] "install" terminal command done
[15:03:54.260] Install terminal quit with output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:03:54.261] Received install output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:03:54.262] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[15:03:54.263] Resolver error: Error: at m.Create (c:\Users\JCY\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:584145) at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\JCY\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:582705) at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\JCY\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:681881) at async c:\Users\JCY\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:644110 at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\JCY\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:647428) at async t.resolve (c:\Users\JCY\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:645160) at async c:\Users\JCY\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remot`e.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:720916
[15:03:54.271] ------
```

Also, "Terminal process was terminated" message popped up at the right-side of the bottom.
i did reinstall vs code, delete .vscode-server folder at remote server, and turn off firewall
but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried the ```Remote - SSH``` vscode extention